# Use a cell value to lookup/navigate to a Sheet with the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm completely new to app-scripts, and not a full-time coder so I'm not sure the right terminologies for describing my issue. Please help me with:

- Returning the value from cell "A1" in a Sheet with the Sheet's name looked-up by a cell value in the ActiveSheet. This is what I have so far:

I cannot get the function to work, and "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null." keeps popping up during debugging,

```js
function obtainvalue(CellVar) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var newsheet = ss.getSheetByName(CellVar);
      var value = newsheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
      return value;
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Are you getting any trouble with your function? Have you already reviewed https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?

Comment: `newsheet.getRange("A1").getValue();`

Comment: It works now, many thanks!